# How to make NetworkManager/nmcli show only non-default settings

Tags: linux, networking, networkmanager

I want to check the settings of a specific NetworkManager connection "myconn". I can do this:

```
nmcli connection show myconn
```

Then it shows me several dozens of setting values which most of them are default values. But I want to just check those that are different from the default. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

`nmcli -o connection show "$PROFILE"`

Short for `--overview`